# How do I calculate the closeness between points/clusters using euclidean distance?

Tags: cluster-analysis, data-mining

Consider a market basket database containing the following 4 transactions over
items 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

**(a)** {1, 2, 3, 5},

**(b)** {2, 3, 4, 5},

**(c)** {1, 4}, and

**(d)** {6}.

The transactions can be viewed as points with boolean (0/1) attributes corresponding to the items 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. The four points thus become

```
(1,1,1,0,1,0),
(0,1,1,1,1,0),
(1,0,0,1,0,0),
(0,0,0,0,0,1).
```

Using euclidean distance to measure the closeness between points/clusters, how do I calculate

- d(1,2)=?
- d(1,3)=?
- d(1,4)=?
- d(2,3)=?
- d(2,4)=?
- d(3,4)=?

(They says d(3,4) = sqrt(3), is it? Is there something missing in the question)

Comment: Euclidean distance on such data does not make a whole lot of sense. In the end, it just boils down to Hamming distance, i.e. **counting how many differences there are**. Then you might just use the real thing (Hamming) instead of the square root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Euclidean distance is defined in your case as:

```
d(i, j) = sqrt( Sum_{k=1..6} (i_k - j_k)^2 )
```

where `i_k` is the k-th item of the i-th transaction and `Sum` means the total sum of those operations.

So you have to iterate over the items to compute those values.